# Spline interpolation

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, cubic-spline

I'm having difficulties to perform a spline interpolation on the below set:

```
import numpy
SOURCE = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5], [9,10,11]])
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
input = [0.5,2,3,6,9,15]
```

The linear interpolation works fine, yet when I replace linear with cubic, I have an error :

```
f = interp1d(SOURCE[:,0], SOURCE[:,1:], kind="linear", axis=0, bounds_error=False)
f(input)

f = interp1d(SOURCE[:,0], SOURCE[:,1:], kind="cubic", axis=0, bounds_error=False)
ValueError: The number of derivatives at boundaries does not match: expected 1, got 0+0
```

How can I perform this cubic interpolation ?

Comment: On some of the interpolaters, this is related to the `order` argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `SOURCE` data is too short. A cubic spline needs at least four points to interpolate from, but you're only provide three. If you add one more value to `SOURCE`, it should work more or less as expected:

```
>>> SOURCE = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5], [9,10,11], [12,13,14]])  # added an extra value
>>> f = interp1d(SOURCE[:,0], SOURCE[:,1:], kind="cubic", axis=0, bounds_error=False)
>>> f(input)
array([[nan, nan],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  5.],
       [ 7.,  8.],
       [10., 11.],
       [nan, nan]])
```

Comment: thanks, I added a bit more data indeed, it's obvious as it needs to approximate the diff for every point... also do you know if there is a possibility to specify the derivate value for extrapolation (either 0 or  [ f(x1) - f(x0) ] / [x1 - x0] for regular or clamped splines ?

Comment: Even I was doing with three points and this problem occured to me. But adding more points solved the issue. Thanks mann!